# Start timer onClick of button from app-widget

Tags: android, android-widget, countdowntimer

I have created one `widget`, which contains a single button which sends message.

Now I want to `disable the same button for 5 Sec after it has been clicked`. And after 5 sec user should be able to send message again.

How can I implement it?

Any URL/ideas appreciated.

Comment: do you mean an app-widget (="home screen widget") ?

Comment: You figured how to do it? Was looking for the same answer

Comment: @Giz : i dont find the solution for disabling the button but yes I displayed toast message if user clicked on button again within 5 sec. For that I used one flag which will be set to true bydefault. On click of button I have started timer(CountDownTimer) and in its finish method same flag is set to false. Each time, on click of button I checked flag value, and based on it, app will either display toast message or will execute required functionality.

Comment: Hey :) Thank you for your reply. Surprisingly, I followed the same method yesterday.  In my case I did not need to enable or disable a button, but was more on audio feedback. Maybe in your case you could use onTick method to disable the button and enable it in onFinish method. It may work. Not very sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Use Android [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) postDelayed method

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}, 5000); // 5 seconds delay
```

Comment: There we go, nicely put together. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always set it to run on another `Thread`, ie first disable the `Button`, `sleep(5000)` in the separate thread and then post to a `Handler` and enable the button once again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when it's clicked and then set an alarm with `AlarmManager` to go off in 5 seconds.

Set the alarm to send an update to your app-widget some flag in the extras that will note it to enable the button.